# Cannot update spyder=5.1.5 on new anaconda install

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I installed anaconda and spyder came with the installation. Spyder 4.2.5 came with the installation and I got a pop up notification that spyder=5.1.5 is available. I tried

> conda update anaconda

> conda install spyder=5.1.5

and gets an error:

`Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.`

I tried letting it run for more than 8 hours, but I had to cancel it because I got tired.

Tried

> conda install anaconda spyder=5.1.5

and gets another error:

`Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- ananconda

Current channels:

- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

```
https://anaconda.org
```

and use the search bar at the top of the page.

Can someone please help on how to solve this?

Comment: Also see https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/16620#issuecomment-950195987 for a potential simple workaround (uninstall spyder and reinstall)

Comment: I'm going to guess this is the issue [After conda update, python kernel crashes when matplotlib is used](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69786885/7758804)

Comment: `conda install -c anaconda spyder=5.1.5` where `-c` specifies `anaconda` as the channel

Answer (score 37, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Our regular instructions to update Spyder don't work in this case because there are some incompatible dependencies between Spyder 5.0.5 and 5.1.5.

To workaround this problem, you need to close Spyder and run the following commands in the Anaconda Prompt (or your system terminal on Linux or macOS):

```
conda remove spyder
conda remove python-language-server
conda update anaconda
conda install spyder=5.1.5
```

The second or third commands (i.e. `conda remove python-language-server` or `conda update anaconda`) could give you errors, but that's fine. Simply ignore them and continue with the other commands.

Comment: @carlose Cordoba conda update anaconda is failing "PackageNotInstalledError: Package is not installed in prefix.
  prefix: C:\Anconda
  package name: anaconda

Comment: Just ignore it and continue with the next command.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it shows a lot of error and some package downgraded, but it is working. I know using a 4.2.5 won't kill me, but it bugs the hell out of me.

Comment: No problem, and glad you decided to update to 5.1.5. We put a lot of effort on that version to fix critical performance issues in the editor, so writing code should be way more pleasant now. A couple more improvements in that area are in the works for 5.2.0, so stay tuned.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba Thank you so much! (Felt like an anonymous-Hacker with all the black screen coding :D ) And btw I hope there won't be any mismatches with this solution and the next update..

Comment: Don't worry, the next updates shouldn't be as difficult as this one.

Answer (score -1):

I used $ conda install -c conda-forge/label/beta spyder
from here https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/spyder and got version 5.0.07a installed.