# Spyder 5.1.5 creates a new kernel after running a custom function

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda, kernel, spyder

I have this problem where everytime I run a script in Python that contains a function, it just crashes and restarts a completely new kernel. The IPython Window then also shows `Restarting kernel...`

I already tried to uninstall and re-install Anaconda and Spyder. I also followed the steps provided in this post:

[cannot update spyder=5.1.5 on new anaconda install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69704561/cannot-update-spyder-5-1-5-on-new-anaconda-install)

After another uninstall and re-install, Spyder (4.2.5) works for a little while. However, after updating anaconda again (`conda update anaconda`) it throws the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'SpyderKernelManager' object has no attribute 'kernel'
```

How to prevent the creation of a new kernel and obtain the output?

Github issue: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/16668

Comment: I'm going to guess this is the issue [After conda update, python kernel crashes when matplotlib is used](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69786885/7758804)

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney It sure is the same issue. I have been discussing this issue on GitHub already with Spyder developers. The accepted answer worked for me, but the downgrade to freetype=2.10.4 also works. The Spyder team is now looking into it, but like you state in your post it is a problem from matplotlibs side. Anyway, good analysis of the problem and feel free to join the discussion here: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/16659

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Possible solution:** The problem seems to be with the newest `matplotlib` function (3.4.3), when I downgraded matplotlib to **3.3.4** again the kernel problem no longer occured.

***Solution:*** Downgrade freetype from 2.11.0 to **2.10.4** by doing `conda install freetype=2.10.4`.