# spyder's kernel dies when I try to make a plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, conda, spyder, freetype

I just updated spyder to 5.1.5 and all it takes is these 4 lines of code to break the kernel:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
arr = np.arange(0,100)
plt.plot(arr)
```

Other plots also fail. Inline plotting also fails. Help!

I made a new environment using anaconda:

```
conda create -n ws_fcst python=3.8 spyder pandas numpy matplotlib scikit-learn sqlalchemy pyodbc
```

Still the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely a duplicate of my problem.

[Spyder 5.1.5 creates a new kernel after running a custom function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69775098/spyder-5-1-5-creates-a-new-kernel-after-running-a-custom-function/69778686#69778686)

There is a potential solution in my answers. Otherwise, you can also downgrade freetype from 2.11.0 to 2.10.4 by doing `conda install freetype=2.10.4` as suggested by Eheran1 in this GitHub post.

https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/16659

Comment: @XiB I am curious which one did you try, the downgrading of matplotlib or the downgrading of freetype?

Comment: Freetype :), I thought that I would start with the smallest change possible.