# Python: matplotlib.pyplot.show() is not showing the plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, matplotlib, miniconda

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1,2,3])
plt.show()

input("Press enter to continue...")
```

If I run the script above within VS Code, or even within command prompt, the plot canvas only flashes for a fraction of a second and the program ends without any error. It doesn't even wait for perssing the Enter.

May be interesting:

- when I installed the Miniconda and set up the environment for the first time it worked. Then I installed `pydicom` I successfully run the test script (with pydicom test image). When I tried to process my own DICOMs it requested for jpeg decoders etc. I installed them, and also others I don't remember. From some point it started to behave like described.
- I tried to roll back to revision I knew it worked `conda install --revision XX`, but that yielded an error
- I removed the environment `conda remove --name myenv --all` and created it from the scratch
- I removed the environment and uninstalled the Miniconda, and redid everything

The problem still remains.

What can be the reason? How can I debug this? Is there any error log?

The environment packages:

```
_tflow_select             2.3.0                       mkl    anaconda
absl-py                   0.10.0                   py38_0    anaconda
aiohttp                   3.6.3            py38he774522_0    anaconda
argon2-cffi               20.1.0           py38h2bbff1b_1
astunparse                1.6.3                      py_0    anaconda
async-timeout             3.0.1                    py38_0    anaconda
async_generator           1.10               pyhd3eb1b0_0
attrs                     21.2.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
backcall                  0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
bayesian-optimization     1.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
blas                      1.0                         mkl    anaconda
bleach                    4.0.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
blinker                   1.4                      py38_0    anaconda
boto3                     1.18.21            pyhd3eb1b0_0
botocore                  1.21.41            pyhd3eb1b0_1
brotli                    1.0.9                ha925a31_2
brotlipy                  0.7.0           py38he774522_1000    anaconda
ca-certificates           2021.10.26           haa95532_2
cachetools                4.1.1                      py_0    anaconda
certifi                   2021.10.8        py38haa95532_0
cffi                      1.14.6           py38h2bbff1b_0
chardet                   3.0.4                 py38_1003    anaconda
charset-normalizer        2.0.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0
click                     7.1.2                      py_0    anaconda
cloudpickle               2.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
colorama                  0.4.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0
cryptography              3.1.1            py38h7a1dbc1_0    anaconda
cycler                    0.10.0                   py38_0
daal4py                   2021.3.0         py38h757b272_0
dal                       2021.3.0           haa95532_564
debugpy                   1.4.1            py38hd77b12b_0
decorator                 5.1.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
defusedxml                0.7.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
entrypoints               0.3                      py38_0
flask                     1.1.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
fonttools                 4.25.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
freetype                  2.11.0               ha860e81_0
gast                      0.4.0                      py_0    anaconda
google-auth               1.22.1                     py_0    anaconda
google-auth-oauthlib      0.4.1                      py_2    anaconda
google-pasta              0.2.0                      py_0    anaconda
grpcio                    1.31.0           py38he7da953_0    anaconda
gym                       0.21.0                   pypi_0    pypi
h5py                      2.10.0           py38h5e291fa_0
hdf5                      1.10.4               h7ebc959_0    anaconda
icc_rt                    2019.0.0             h0cc432a_1    anaconda
icu                       58.2                 ha925a31_3
idna                      2.10                       py_0    anaconda
importlib-metadata        4.8.1            py38haa95532_0
importlib_metadata        4.8.1                hd3eb1b0_0
intel-openmp              2020.2                      254    anaconda
ipykernel                 6.4.1            py38haa95532_1
ipython                   7.27.0           py38hd4e2768_0
ipython_genutils          0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1
ipywidgets                7.6.5              pyhd3eb1b0_1
itsdangerous              2.0.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
jedi                      0.18.0           py38haa95532_1
jinja2                    3.0.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
jmespath                  0.10.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
joblib                    1.1.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
jpeg                      9d                   h2bbff1b_0
jsonschema                3.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_2
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py38_7
jupyter_client            7.0.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
jupyter_console           6.4.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
jupyter_core              4.8.1            py38haa95532_0
jupyterlab_pygments       0.1.2                      py_0
jupyterlab_widgets        1.0.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1
kaggle                    1.5.12                   pypi_0    pypi
keras-applications        1.0.8                      py_1    anaconda
keras-preprocessing       1.1.0                      py_1    anaconda
kiwisolver                1.3.1            py38hd77b12b_0
libiconv                  1.15                 h1df5818_7
libpng                    1.6.37               h2a8f88b_0
libprotobuf               3.13.0.1             h200bbdf_0    anaconda
libtiff                   4.2.0                hd0e1b90_0
libwebp                   1.2.0                h2bbff1b_0
libxml2                   2.9.12               h0ad7f3c_0
libxslt                   1.1.34               he774522_0
lxml                      4.6.3            py38h9b66d53_0
lz4-c                     1.9.3                h2bbff1b_1
m2w64-gcc-libgfortran     5.3.0                         6
m2w64-gcc-libs            5.3.0                         7
m2w64-gcc-libs-core       5.3.0                         7
m2w64-gmp                 6.1.0                         2
m2w64-libwinpthread-git   5.0.0.4634.697f757               2
markdown                  3.3.2                    py38_0    anaconda
markupsafe                2.0.1            py38h2bbff1b_0
matplotlib                3.4.3            py38haa95532_0
matplotlib-base           3.4.3            py38h49ac443_0
matplotlib-inline         0.1.2              pyhd3eb1b0_2
mistune                   0.8.4           py38he774522_1000
mkl                       2019.4                      245    anaconda
mkl-service               2.3.0            py38hb782905_0    anaconda
mkl_fft                   1.2.0            py38h45dec08_0    anaconda
mkl_random                1.1.0            py38hf9181ef_0    anaconda
msys2-conda-epoch         20160418                      1
multidict                 4.7.6            py38he774522_1    anaconda
munkres                   1.1.4                      py_0
nb_conda                  2.2.1                    py38_1
nb_conda_kernels          2.3.1            py38haa95532_0
nbclient                  0.5.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
nbconvert                 6.1.0            py38haa95532_0
nbformat                  5.1.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
nest-asyncio              1.5.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
notebook                  6.4.5            py38haa95532_0
numpy                     1.19.1           py38h5510c5b_0    anaconda
numpy-base                1.19.1           py38ha3acd2a_0    anaconda
oauthlib                  3.1.0                      py_0    anaconda
olefile                   0.46               pyhd3eb1b0_0
openssl                   1.1.1l               h2bbff1b_0
opt_einsum                3.1.0                      py_0    anaconda
packaging                 21.0               pyhd3eb1b0_0
pandas                    1.2.4            py38hf11a4ad_0
pandas-datareader         0.10.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
pandocfilters             1.4.3            py38haa95532_1
parso                     0.8.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pickleshare               0.7.5           pyhd3eb1b0_1003
pillow                    8.4.0            py38hd45dc43_0
pip                       21.2.2           py38haa95532_0
prometheus_client         0.11.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
prompt-toolkit            3.0.20             pyhd3eb1b0_0
prompt_toolkit            3.0.20               hd3eb1b0_0
protobuf                  3.13.0.1         py38ha925a31_1    anaconda
pyasn1                    0.4.8                      py_0    anaconda
pyasn1-modules            0.2.8                      py_0    anaconda
pycparser                 2.20                       py_2
pygments                  2.10.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyjwt                     1.7.1                    py38_0    anaconda
pyopenssl                 19.1.0                     py_1    anaconda
pyparsing                 3.0.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyqt                      5.9.2            py38ha925a31_4
pyreadline                2.1                      py38_1    anaconda
pyrsistent                0.17.3           py38he774522_0
pysocks                   1.7.1                    py38_0    anaconda
python                    3.8.12               h6244533_0
python-dateutil           2.8.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
python-slugify            5.0.2                    pypi_0    pypi
pytz                      2021.3             pyhd3eb1b0_0
pywin32                   228              py38hbaba5e8_1
pywinpty                  0.5.7                    py38_0
pyyaml                    6.0              py38h2bbff1b_1
pyzmq                     22.2.1           py38hd77b12b_1
qt                        5.9.7            vc14h73c81de_0
qtconsole                 5.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
qtpy                      1.10.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
requests                  2.26.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
requests-oauthlib         1.3.0                      py_0    anaconda
rsa                       4.6                        py_0    anaconda
s3transfer                0.5.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
scikit-learn              1.0.1            py38hf11a4ad_0
scikit-learn-intelex      2021.3.0         py38haa95532_0
scipy                     1.6.2            py38h14eb087_0
send2trash                1.8.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1
setuptools                58.0.4           py38haa95532_0
sip                       4.19.13          py38ha925a31_0
six                       1.16.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
sqlite                    3.36.0               h2bbff1b_0
tbb                       2021.4.0             h59b6b97_0
tensorboard               2.6.0                      py_1
tensorboard-data-server   0.6.0            py38haa95532_0
tensorboard-plugin-wit    1.6.0                      py_0    anaconda
tensorflow                2.3.0           mkl_py38h37f7ee5_0
tensorflow-base           2.3.0           eigen_py38h75a453f_0
tensorflow-estimator      2.3.0              pyheb71bc4_0    anaconda
termcolor                 1.1.0                    py38_1    anaconda
terminado                 0.9.4            py38haa95532_0
testpath                  0.5.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
text-unidecode            1.3                      pypi_0    pypi
threadpoolctl             2.2.0              pyh0d69192_0
tk                        8.6.11               h2bbff1b_0
tornado                   6.1              py38h2bbff1b_0
tqdm                      4.62.3             pyhd3eb1b0_1
traitlets                 5.1.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
urllib3                   1.25.11                    py_0    anaconda
vc                        14.2                 h21ff451_1
vs2015_runtime            14.27.29016          h5e58377_2
wcwidth                   0.2.5              pyhd3eb1b0_0
webencodings              0.5.1                    py38_1
werkzeug                  1.0.1                      py_0    anaconda
wheel                     0.37.0             pyhd3eb1b0_1
widgetsnbextension        3.5.1                    py38_0
win_inet_pton             1.1.0                    py38_0    anaconda
wincertstore              0.2              py38haa95532_2
winpty                    0.4.3                         4
wrapt                     1.12.1           py38he774522_1    anaconda
xz                        5.2.5                h62dcd97_0
yaml                      0.2.5                he774522_0
yarl                      1.6.2            py38he774522_0    anaconda
zipp                      3.6.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
zlib                      1.2.11           vc14h1cdd9ab_1  [vc14]  anaconda
zstd                      1.4.9                h19a0ad4_0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of late, conda and `matplotlib` have been having issues.

You can try to downgrade freetype from **2.11.0 to 2.10.4** by doing `conda install freetype=2.10.4`

Comment: Relevant bug report: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/21511

Comment: As an FYI, when you know a question is a duplicate, it is appropriate to flag the question as a duplicate, not post the same answer again. You have already posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69778686/7758804) based on the solution I provided to you. Posting the same solution to multiple questions is also a violation of SO rules.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney Sorry, I flagged it as well. Won't happen again, was just trying to provide a quick help. Should I delete this answer?