# cannot set 'home/user/anaconda3/bin/python' as python path on spyder?

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, pythonpath

I reinstalled spyder on my system (Ubuntu) to update it to the 5.1.5 version; I did it following the solution of this post: [Spyder 5.1.5 update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69704561/cannot-update-spyder-5-1-5-on-new-anaconda-install)
Now I have to set the python path. I don't want to create a new environment but just access to all conda python library.
The output of these commands

```
conda activate
which python
```

is:

```
/home/emanuele/anaconda3/bin/python
```

On the other hand, when I open spyder and goes to **Tool -> PYTHONPATH manager**, I'm not able to find this path: inside the bin there is no the python folder as expected[image]

What am I missing? Any idea of how to solve it?

Comment: Note that PYTHONPATH does not deal with which Python executable is used. That is what PATH is for.

Comment: You're not seeing anything, because the filter of the file picker is set to "directories". It expects a directory for PYTHONPATH; *not* the Python executable. The Spyder setting for the Python executable is probably somewhere else.

Comment: Thank you for your comment; so what is the right way to identify the path to use in the PYTHONPATH manager?

Comment: https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/faq.html#using-existing-environment

Comment: I'm not so practical, is there a guide that explain how to configure spyder properly? For example in the above link is not clear to me which path I should select; I don't have/want to create a new env; just want to link spyder with the standard anaconda's collections of python's libraries

Comment: You select `/home/emanuele/anaconda3/bin/python` there. Yes, the manual calls it "environment", but that's just to confuse you.

Comment: Thank you! I realized that interpreter was well set (in the post's picture, lower right part is reported conda:base (Python 3.8.12)) and that I simply lost some library as matplotlib; once I pip installed them again all seems to works fine

Comment: To be honest: it is a bit weird that you install Conda, but then don't use the environment(s) *and* pip-install e.g. matplotlib. In that case, you could have simply installed a recent Python version, without the Conda stuff.