# Spyder Refreshing Variable Explorer

Tags: python, spyder

I am using both of sypder 4.0 and spyder 5.0 with python 3.8.

When I restrat kernel, the variable explorer is not refreshed sometimes.

I do not find the condition to make it not to be refreshed.

How can I fix it?

I run the code with the kernel.
[image]

I refresh the kernel but the variable explorer is not refreshed.

[image]

Unfortunately, when I updated to the 4.2.5, it does not work.

[image: Updated version]

Comment: have you selected the refresh option (last one upper, right to the search symbol )

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) What's your Spyder version? I think we fixed this some months ago.

Comment: @UlisesBussi I tried the refresh button, howerver it still leave there. The only way to remove them is to make new kernel, rather than re-start it.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba My version is 4.1.5.

Comment: Ok, then please update to our 4.2.5 version and try again. You can do that with the commands `conda update anaconda` and then `conda install spyder=4.2.5`

Comment: @CarlosCordoba Thank you for the suggestion. However, unfortunately, when I follow the instruction, it still does not work. I attached the third screenshot in the main article. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, you could try to update to our latest version available in Anaconda (5.1.5) to see if the problem persists. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69704561/cannot-update-spyder-5-1-5-on-new-anaconda-install/69713849#69713849) for the corresponding instructions (they also apply to 4.2.5).