# Application launch error in Anaconda Navigator - Application spyder launch may have produced errors

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I've followed these steps in order to update Spyder:

conda remove spyder
conda remove python-language-server
conda update anaconda
conda install spyder=5.1.5

As advised in post [Cannot update spyder=5.1.5 on new anaconda install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69704561/cannot-update-spyder-5-1-5-on-new-anaconda-install)

However, I cannot open Spyder anymore form my anaconda navigator...

It gives me the error:
Application spyder launch may have produced error
/Users/me/opt/anaconda3/bin/pythonw: line 3: /Users/me/opt/anaconda3/python.app/Contents/MacOS/python: No such file or directory

Does anyone know what the issue might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i ran into the same problem. I solved it now, here is what i have done. 
***Steps to fix it***:

- open your terminal
- navigate to `/opt/anaconda3/bin`
- type `nano pythonw`
- the last line of the file should read `/opt/anaconda3/python.app/Contents/MacOS/python "$@"`
- this line should be `/opt/anaconda3/python.app/pythonapp/Contents/MacOS/python "$@"` (the `pythonapp` part is missing)
- safe and close
- it should work now

Explanation: 
There is a file named `python`, but in a different path (`/opt/anaconda3/python.app/pythonapp/Contents/MacOS/python`). So I guess, that the internal path is set wrong or somebody forgot to change it. That means, that as soon as you hit the "launch" button, the navigator is looking at the wrong place. We either have to adjust that path manually or wait for a solution from the development team. 
Hope i could help

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) This can also be solved by running `conda install --force-reinstall python.app`

Comment: @CarlosCordoba but this command only works in the spyder console? if we are unable to launch the spyder app we can not run this command or am i missing something?

Comment: No, it's meant to be run in a Terminal.app, like any other conda command.

Comment: @Tess glad to hear, you can mark my comment as a solution to indicate new people that it works