# Spyder 5.1.5 cannot launch in Anaconda Navigator 2.2.0 in Mac OS

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I am very new to coding but have been using Spyder to learn and carry out some tasks for my role (not IT-related). I have not used it for a few months but today when I tried to launch Spyder, it showed the "Application launch error" with the following message:

/Users/harry/opt/anaconda3/bin/pythonw: line 3: 25747 Terminated: 15          /Users/harry/opt/anaconda3/python.app/Contents/MacOS/python "$@"

I have uninstalled and reinstalled Anaconda Navigator but nothing's changed.

Any help will be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: This is a kind of old issue but seems like the traceback is quite similar: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/9951 Seems like you need to install `python.app` as described here: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/9951#issuecomment-517913824

Comment: Hi @DanielAlthviz thank you for your reply! I've tried installing python.app but it didn't work
Though I think the below solution would work, can you please explain how I can change directory?
Attempted Solution
I opened /Users/xyan/anaconda3/bin/pythonw, which is simply:

#!/bin/bash
export PYTHONEXECUTABLE=/Users/xyan/anaconda3/bin/python
/Users/xyan/anaconda3/python.app/Contents/MacOS/python "$@"
while I found the python binary is actually in

/Users/xyan/anaconda3/python.app/pythonapp/Contents/MacOS/python

I changed the directory manually and spyder can launch without problem.

Comment: Maybe this could be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70856617/15954282 . However seems like forcing the `python.app` install should have solved that problem. Did you have any Python related things running while running the `conda install -f python.app` from the terminal?

Comment: @DanielAlthviz again thanks for the help! I didn't have any Python related things running while running the `conda install -f python.app`. Don't know what happened but today when I tried launching Spyder it just started without any issues..... Still really appreciate your help on this Dan, all the best to you!

Comment: Glad is working for you now!