# Installing GeoPandas on Spyder 5.1.5

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, geopandas

Since updating Spyder to version 5.1.5, I'm unable to install GeoPandas. I've tried the following:

`conda install geopandas`

`conda install --channel conda-forge geopandas`

`conda install -c conda-forge geopandas`

and

```
conda create -n geo_env
conda activate geo_env
conda config --env --add channels conda-forge
conda config --env --set channel_priority strict
conda install python=3 geopandas
```

and none seem to work. I've also installed all the necessary dependencies, with the exception of Fiona (which returns the same installation problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research and a [helpful post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69704561/cannot-update-spyder-5-1-5-on-new-anaconda-install), I figured out a solution. There must have been an error when I previously updated Spyder to 5.1.5, and even though I had uninstalled and reinstalled Anaconda a number of times, GeoPandas wouldn't install until I removed Spyder through the Anaconda Prompt.

`conda remove spyder`

`conda remove python-language-server` (may return error but not a problem)

`conda update anaconda` (may return error but not a problem)

`conda install spyder=5.1.5`

`conda install pandas`

`conda install geopandas`

`conda install openpyxl` (had to reinstall)